# How to read different levels of groups in HDF5 with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have been looking for any pythonic/panda-esque ways to read groups hierarchically in HDF5 files. For example, if I have this as my h5 layout:

```
h5 file 
    - group1 #level 1
        - table1 # level 2
        - table2
    - group2
        - table2
            -metadataTable #level 3
        - table5
```

Obviously you can get the keys with the .keys() method. But this returns a list of:

```
hdf.keys() = ["/group1/table1", "/group1/table2", "/group2/table2/metadataTable", "/group2/table5"]
```

But is it possible to just get keys with Pandas like this:

```
#just 1st level keys
hdf.someMethodForKeys() = ["/group1", "/group2"] # if there is a method to return a list of one hierarchy level
```

Or get keys from a different level:

```
# just 2nd level keys
hdf.someMethodForKeys() =  ["/group1/table1", "/group1/table2", "/group2/table2", "/group2/table5"]
```

I know you could do some parsing once you get the list from the .keys() method and sort it that way, but I was just wondering if there is some way to do this conveniently with Pandas. The keys in the h5 file are not necessarily coherently or conventionally named (h5 files may have different types of data tables from different fields of research...).

Comment: Can you post an example file. I think you can iterate through each group: [hdf[key].keys() for key in hdf.keys()] but it is hard to test it without example

Comment: Are you open to using h5py or pytables? Both have methods to recursively "walk" the group/dataset hierarchy of a HDF5 file . With h5py, use `.visititems()` method. With pytables, use `.walk_nodes()` or `.walk_groups()`  methods.

Comment: I have tried iterating through using the hdfstore.keys() method. I am unable to post an example file on SO, and in terms of the .keys() function it gives me each leaf node of the h5 hierarchy, whereas I would like to just iterate/get a list of a single level of nodes on the hierarchy.
```
hdf = pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'r')
        for key in hdf.keys():
            print(key)```

As for the h5py or pytables, I already extensively use Pandas for this application/project. I'm not sure if it would be considered good practice to use both h5py and Pandas, but if you think so then I'll try it